# weird calculation result

Tags: c++

why `d` is not equal `b` in this example?

```
  unsigned int z = 176400;
  long a = -4;
  long b = a*z/1000; //b=4294261
  long c = a*z; // c=-705600
  long d = c/1000; // d =-705
```

I use Visual Studio 2008, windows XP, core2duo.
Thanks.

Comment: ... Because d == c/1000. Is this a real life?

Comment: @crushanator In fact, a is also not equal to d. Did you see that?

Comment: Why is 1 not equal to 2 in this example: `int a = 1; int b = 2;`?

Comment: My guess is that you meant to ask why `b` and `d` are not equal. Is that so? If that is so then please do edit the question that way and we can reopen it.

Comment: Are they equal > _-705600 = -705_ ?

Comment: @David Heffernan, yes, edited question.

Comment: @crushanator Good. I've voted to reopen and hopefully we can get this question open again.

Comment: @crushanator: works for me. What compiler are you using? What's your platform (including processor)?

Comment: @outis, Visual Studio 2008, windows XP, core2duo.

Comment: @crushanator: please update the question with your platform & compiler. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using a platform where `int` and `long` have the same size. (I've inferred this by the fact that if `long` was able to hold all the valid values of `unsigned int` you would not see the behaviour that you are seeing.)

This means that in the expression `a*z`, both `a` and `z` are converted to `unsigned long` and the result has type `unsigned long`. (ISO/IEC 14882:2011, 5 [expr] / 9 ... "Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.")

`c` is the result of converting this expression from `unsigned long` to `long` and in your case this results in an implementation defined result (that happens to be negative) as the positive value of `a*z` is not representable in a signed `long`. In `c/1000`, `1000` is converted to `long` and `long` division is performed (no pun intended) resulting in a `long` (which happens to be negative) and is stored to `d`.

In the expressions `a*z/1000`, `1000` (an expression of type `int`) is converted to `unsigned long` and the division is performed between two `unsigned long` resulting in a positive result. This result is representable as a `long` and the value is unchanged on converting to `long` and storing to `b`.

Comment: This is infact the case on MS C compiler.

Comment: Signed overflow is undefined behaviour, but the way.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, but there is no signed overflow in this example.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: You're trying to convert a value to `long` that's too big for that type - isn't that overflow?

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, that's just an integral conversion with an implementation-defined result. Overflow describes the situation where an arithmetic operation results in something that exceeds the bounds of the type on which it is operating.

Comment: The incorrect answer comes much earlier, from the conversion of `-4` to `unsigned long`, which can't hold that value.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But signed-to-unsigned conversions *are* well-defined.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, probably not the desired result but the conversion of `-4` to `unsigned long` is well defined and doesn't differ between the calcuation of `b` and `d`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Yes, but from that point forward, the value has lost its meaning.  It doesn't make much sense to talk about "the positive value of `a*z`" when the actual product is negative.  You just have the result of integer multiplications as a bit pattern, which is interpreted as positive in `a*z/1000` and interpreted as negative when the signed temporary is introduced to hold the intermediate value.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I disagree. I've explained why the two operands of `a*z` are converted to unsigned types so I think it is correct to describe the expression `a*z` (this is C++, not math) as having a positive value.